# Every 4 div wrapped in a div

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

There is such a loop, I want to get 4 repetitions of the div with the class tabs__cat-img and these 4 div should turn into a div with the class tabs_ _ cat. I will be grateful for any help.

```php
<?php
    if($children_categories) :
    foreach($children_categories as $children_cat) :
?>
<div class="tabs__cat">
    <div class="tabs__cat-img">
        <a href="">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    endforeach;
    endif;
?>
```

The output should look like this:

```php
<div class="tabs__cat">
    <div class="tabs__cat-img">
        <a href="">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs__cat-img">
        <a href="">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs__cat-img">
        <a href="">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs__cat-img">
        <a href="">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tabs__cat"> ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
<?php
// Creates a sample array
$children_categories = array_fill(0, 10, 'Sample');

if($children_categories) :

    $total_categories = count($children_categories) - 1;

    foreach($children_categories as $id=>$children_cat) :

    // True for 0 -> Div will be created on first and then every 4th element
    if( $id % 4 === 0 ) { 
        echo '<div class="tabs__cat">';
    }
    // or, a bit shorter: 
    // echo $id % 4 === 0 ? '<div class="tabs__cat">' : '';

    ?>

    <div class="tabs__cat-img">
        <a href="">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <?php

    // True on 3 -> closing Div will be created before 4th and then every 4th element
    // Or Case: Make sure to print closing div on very last element
    if( $id % 4 === 3 || $id === $total_categories ) { 
        echo '</div>';
    }

    endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The first div tabs__cat-img turned into a div tabs__cat, and the rest were left without a wrapper https://yadi.sk/i/Rni9RYBp5sS9ew

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the last if statement: it said count( $children_cat ) but it should of course count the complete array: count( $children_categories ). I also moved the count out of the foreach loop so it only needs to be calculated once

Comment: The page doesn't open, HTTP 500 ERROR (((

Comment: I dont know if you hat the children array already, so i also added in a sample array. Take the complete code and paste it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ - and then click execute code. You should see that it work. If you dont get it to run please post the code you have running on your system.

Comment: Oh Yes, Your code works correctly. But I also get a 500 error(

Comment: I added the full code from the file http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4bbe281c5a34f43e95d125266285e5b247969382

Comment: Ok now you get an error on the sandbox because you threw your complete code in there. Of course the sandbox doesn't know the wordpress functions, so that's why it says the functions dont exist. But if the "every 4th"-thing works now great :) Don't forget to give an upvote / mark my answer as solution please - only if you feel that it helped of course. Thanks mate!

Comment: The fact is that the site goes to 500 error, that is, for some reason it does not work on my site, although in fact your current code works. Of course I will mark Your code as useful, thank you for your help! But if you look at what needs to be done in relation to my code, I will be very grateful)

Comment: You need to send the error message, otherwise I can't know:)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your code a little bit.
I moved the parent div which has class `tabs__cat` from the `foreach` loop.

```
<?php
$children_categories = array_fill(0, 4, 'Sample');

    if($children_categories) :
    echo '<div class="tabs__cat">'; // small changed here
    foreach($children_categories as $children_cat) :
?>

    <div class="tabs__cat-img">
        <a href="">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>

<?php
    endforeach;
    echo '</div>'; // small changed here
    endif;
?>
```